# Dynamically get previous element then clicked in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a list of links and buttons with class names dynamically generated in php using a foreach loop. An example output is:

```
<a class="edit-url-9rwpaZV" href="page/1">This is my title</a>
<button class="edit-btn-9rwpaZV" data-text-swap="Save">Edit</button>

<a class="edit-url-5R8eBR2M" href="page/2">Why tea is great</a>
<button class="edit-btn-5R8eBR2M" data-text-swap="Save">Edit</button>

<a class="edit-url-V7Ma8Olb" href="page/3">Fish are friends</a>
<button class="edit-btn-V7Ma8Olb" data-text-swap="Save">Edit</button>
```

I have jQuery functions that fire off when the "Edit" button is pressed so I can edit the text of the link and save it via ajax.

An example of these functions is like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   editing=false;
   c = $(".edit-url");
   b = $(".edit-btn").click(toggle_edit);
   toggle_edit();
});

function toggle_edit()
{
  switch(editing){
    case true:
      c.get(0).contentEditable = true;
      c.css({background:"#eeeeee"});
      editing=false;
    break;
    case false:
      c.get(0).contentEditable = false;
      c.css({background:"white"});
      editing=true;
  break;
  }
}
```

Previously (before I added a unique identifier to each class name) when I clicked ***any*** button it made all ".edit-url" links editable, but I don't want all fields to be editable, I only wanted the field to the left of each button to be editable (i.e. only one field).

What I want to know is, how can I add a wildcard/variable to my selector, so that when I click, for example, "edit-btn-V7Ma8Olb" it makes the "edit-url-V7Ma8Olb" field editable only and not all the other fields?

**SOLUTION**

Ended up using .()prev like suggested below: http://jsfiddle.net/1yncv6rf/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var editable=1;
    $(".edit-btn").click(function(){
         if(editable == 1){
             $(this).prev().attr('contenteditable','true');
             return editable=2;
         } else if(editable == 2) {
              $(this).prev().attr('contenteditable','false');
              return editable=1;
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use [jQuery.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    editing=false;
    c = $(".edit-url");
    b = $(".edit-btn").click(function(){
        var elementToEdit = $(this).prev();
        switch(editing){
            case true:
            elementToEdit.contentEditable = true;
            elementToEdit.css({background:"#eeeeee"});
            editing=false;
        break;
        case false:
            elementToEdit.contentEditable = false;
            elementToEdit.css({background:"white"});
            editing=true;
        break;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using .prev() good idea! My solution is in the edit above.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you to do little bit of Research on $(this) selector jquery that will grab only cilcked button and then you find relative $(".edit-url") DOM object using jquery.previous.